# not being able vs not able

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which one is grammatical and the reason?

> The virus can mutate, and this makes the current method **not being able**
>   to detect it.
>
> The virus can mutate, and this makes the current method **not able** to
>   detect it.

Answer (score 0):

**make sb/sth able to do sth**
then, the latter is correct.
but it would be better to use **unable** in lieu of "not able"
The virus can mutate making the current method unable to detect it.